# How to prove a power series can be analytically continued?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Consider the complex function $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}z^{2n+1} \, .$

(i) Determine its domain.

(ii) Let $\Gamma = \{iy:y\in\mathbb{R}, |y| \geq 1 \}$, show that there exists an analytic continuation of $f$ to $\mathbb{C}-\Gamma$.

(iii) (optional) Discuss the existence of other maximal analytical continuations of $f$ to domains of the Riemann sphere $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ of the form $D= (\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\})-\Gamma',$ where $\Gamma'$ is a compact set of $\mathbb{C}$.

For the first part: I think the radius of convergence is $1$. And I can see it converges when $z=1$, but I don't know about the rest of the border $S^1$. However, the real problem is point (ii). Is there a general way to tackle this kind of problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

For $|z|<1$, we have

$$f'(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-z^2)^n \tag 1$$

Now, find $f(z)$ by evaluating the geometric series in $(1)$ and integrating the result.  Finally, note that the function $f(z)$ extended beyond the unit circle has branch points at $\pm i$.

Comment: So $f(z)=\tan^{-1}(z)-z$ ?

Comment: @unumileappassionato Yes, that is correct.  And the arctangent has branch points at $\pm i$ with branch cuts emanating from the branch points to $\infty$.  We can choose to cut the plane along the imaginary axis whence the result is as described in (ii) of the OP.  -Mark

Comment: Thanks, that was really simple. I had never met the complex inverse tangent before, so what I say may be totally wrong, but if $\tan^{-1}$ behaves like other complex functions, then branch cuts emanating from $\pm i$ can assume an arbitrary direction, right? That would be my attempt to answer point (iii).

Comment: In fact, the branch cuts do not have to be straight lines.  Here, we can choose to cut the along the imaginary axis from $z=-i$ to $z=i$, for example.  Then, the function $f(z)=\arctan(z)-z$ is analytic outside the unit circle and on the unit circle less the branch points.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt very much that there is a **very** general way to determine when a power series has an analytic continuation outside its radius $R$ of convergence.  You're unlikely to be able to find a domain for a maximal analytic continuation unless you can find a closed form for the function (or for the difference between the function and some entire function).

One thing you can sometimes do is to identify a finite number of points of the circle of radius $R$ where the series "goes bad", and see whether subtracting a suitable function with poles or branch points at those points leaves you with a series having greater radius of convergence.

There are also some sufficient conditions for the function to have a natural boundary on the circle of convergence, notably the [Ostrowski–Hadamard gap theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%E2%80%93Hadamard_gap_theorem).

Comment: Ok, so in problems like this I should probably aim to find a closed form for $f$. Also, I did not know Ostrowski-Hadamard gap theorem. Thank you.